# SoapClient exhausting memory

Tags: php, memory, soap

I'm writing a script that uses SoapClient.

When i run the script i get Memory Limit error from PHP. I originally thought that i was passing to much data. But the error already comes when calling the SoapClient constructer.

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl, array("trace" => 1, "exceptions" => 1));
```

The SoapClient is trying to allocate almost 2gb of data. This seems a bit crazy to me.

Does anyone have an idea what could be wrong?

I'm running PHP 5.3.27 with following Soap settings:

soap.wsdl_cache_enabled 1
soap.wsdl_cache_limit   5
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl 86400

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a couple of bug reports that might relate to the PHP version:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62337 
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=36517

However i "solved" this problem for myself by disabling soap.wsdl_cache_enabled.

What is causing the error when enabling caching i do not know.

Comment: This just worked for me, error came out of nowhere on PHP 7.1